# How to iterate through table and collect in three different arrays values from that fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to iterate through table, using JQuery, and collect in three different arrays values from that fields ?
I have rows like

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="name_x"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="op_x"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="val_x"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

where x is different in every row ( but all starts with name_, op_ and val_  ). How to collect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$('tr').each(function(i,el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    str1 = $this.find('select[id^="name_"]').val();
    str2 = $this.find('select[id^="op_"]').val();
    str3 = $this.find('input[id^="val_"]').val();
    // now do what you like with those strings
});
```